# Referencing a Windows path for a volume in Docker

Tags: windows, docker, docker-volume

So I’m trying to investigate this interesting photo management tool [Damselfly](https://github.com/Webreaper/Damselfly?tab=readme-ov-file) and though it supports running directly under Windows 10 the documentation is purposely incomplete and while I got it running for the most part it eventually hard crashed my machine. So I am trying to use the Docker setup which I can get to run but it doesn’t see my pictures.

This is the startup command:

```
docker run \
  --name damselfly \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  -v /volume1/dockerdata/damselfly:/config \
  -v m:/charles/Dropbox/graphics:/pictures \
  -v /volume1/dockerdata/damselfly/thumbs:/thumbs \
  -p 6363:6363 \
  -d \
  webreaper/damselfly
```

I have tried a number of tips from here, the Docker forums and other web searches to no avail. I have seen examples of using `mount` but none of them worked or I couldn’t adapt them properly.

Bottom line, how do you use a Windows path as the location a Docker volume references under Windows?